# Woocommerce - Remove country field in cart shipping

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

How would I have Australia selected by default and have the input field not displaying heres an example of what im talking about I am using woocommerce:

[image]

I'm sure there is a simple function for this or setting in the back end but can't seem to find a solution :(

Answer (score 6):

Paste following code into your function.php file to Remove country field in checkout page:

```
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields )    
{
unset($fields['billing']['billing_country']);
return $fields;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields','custom_override_checkout_fields');
```

Comment: This works, but for me, it made 'city' field become 100% width and postcode stays 50% and its in a new line (before, they were both 50%, side by side and city was AFTER postcode - float:right). Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: This removes the country field in the checkout page. The author requested to remove the field on the cart page.

Answer (score 4):

You can set your store to only sell to Australia in the WooCommerce Settings> General Settings in the "Specific Countries" field

[image: restrict the countries you will sell to]

This should remove the Country option from the checkout. With "Australia" set in the above settings here is the result in Twenty Fourteen:

[image: checkout with no country option]

Comment: Hi thanks for your attempt but I already have these settings set and the country field is still on the cart page

Comment: In must be something in your theme (or other plugins then) because I just set my test setup to only sell to Australia (don't forget the Selling Location=specific countries option) and do not see the country on the checkout. See the screenshot I've added.

Comment: Sorry should of been more specific it's only on the shopping cart page when you use the shipping calculator

Comment: Ok. I think the easiest thing would be just to hide that field with CSS. `#calc_shipping_country_field{ display: none; }`. Otherwise, you are looking at overriding the `cart/shipping-calculator.php` template.

Comment: Thanks I was trying to avoid css hacks, but it was the solution I ended up going with

Answer (score 0):

// insert into functions.php your theme. Resolved!

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_calculator_enable_country', '__return_false' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_calculator_enable_city', '__return_false' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_calculator_enable_state', '__return_false' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your store to only sell to Specific Countries in the WooCommerce Settings> General Settings in the "Specific Countries" field and hide the woocommerce billing contry field using CSS:

#billing_country_field {display:none;}

Answer (score -3):

A bit late but still for those who looking for correct answer

```
// Remove Country field from shipping calculator
add_filter('woocommerce_shipping_calculator_enable_country','__return_false');
```

Comment: This seems to break the shipping calculator because now there is no country value and the location is not valid.  I think the best way to do this is actually CSS.  This would work, but you'd have to hard-code in the country as a hidden field in the form, I don't know if that's possible with WooCommerce hooks, but it seems like it's probably not worth the effort if you can just limit the options in the WooCommerce settings and then hide it with CSS.