# How can i disable a select2 drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, jquery-select2

I want to disable a select2 dropdown on woocommerce checkout page.I want that the user can't change the country from the drop down on checkout page

I do not want to hide the field(country) but want just to disable the drop down

This is how html looks for the drop down

```
<div class="select2-drop select2-display-none select2-with-searchbox select2-drop-active" style="left: 92.5px; width: 556px; top: 668px; bottom: auto; display: block;" id="select2-drop">   

    <div class="select2-search">      
        <label for="s2id_autogen1_search" class="select2-offscreen">Country *</label>       
        <input type="text" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" class="select2-input" role="combobox" aria-expanded="true" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-owns="select2-results-1" id="s2id_autogen1_search" placeholder="" aria-activedescendant="select2-result-label-7">   
    </div>   
    <ul class="select2-results" role="listbox" id="select2-results-1">
        <li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable select2-highlighted" role="presentation">
            <div class="select2-result-label" id="select2-result-label-7" role="option">
            <span class="select2-match">
            </span>
            India
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable" role="presentation">
            <div class="select2-result-label" id="select2-result-label-8" role="option">
            <span class="select2-match"></span>
            United Kingdom (UK)
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Woocommerce - Remove country field in cart shipping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29588992/woocommerce-remove-country-field-in-cart-shipping)

Comment: @ArcaneCraeda hey thanks for helping,,,  but that will just remove the country field from the checkout page. And I am sure client will say they want the country field to be there but want it disabled  ..   :(    Anyways thanks ,,,

Comment: I see. You can set your store to only sell to one country in "WooCommerce Settings" > "General Settings", in the "Specific Countries" field. Check out the answer below the one I linked and report back if it worked.

Comment: yup thats not the case too , i am selling to four countries .. countries get selected automatically based on the category of the product in the cart, one category for each country

Answer (score 2):

you can do it like this...

```
function rei_woocommerce_form_field_args($args, $key, $value) {

    if ($key == 'billing_country') {
        $args['custom_attributes'] = array('disabled'=>'disabled');

    }
    return $args;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_form_field_args', 'rei_woocommerce_form_field_args', 10, 3);
```

add it to your `functions.php`...

***I do hope you realized that disabled form fields don't get included in the POST / GET data.***

if you really need this, we can add extra hidden input that has the same name and value for the select.. all together now, it should be like this..

```
function rei_woocommerce_form_field_args($args, $key, $value) {

    if (($key == 'billing_country') && is_checkout()) {
        $args['custom_attributes'] = array('disabled'=>'disabled');
    }
    return $args;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_form_field_args', 'rei_woocommerce_form_field_args', 10, 3);

function rei_woocommerce_form_field_country($field, $key, $args, $value){

    if (($key == 'billing_country') && is_checkout()) {
        $field .= '<input type="hidden" name="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '" value="' . esc_attr( $value ) . '" />';
    }
    return $field;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_form_field_country','rei_woocommerce_form_field_country', 10, 4);
```

Another note is that, even if you can disable the select, anyone who has the knowledge can easily removed the disabled property in the browser.

Comment: hey thanks , i tried your code , it does exactly what i wanted,,   i walso able to acheive this using js.  But now only i came to know that disabled form fields don't get included in the POST / GET data.    So everything is of no use then. Thanks again

Comment: you can add hidden input with the same name and value.. that will be included in the get or post

Answer (score 0):

Two workarounds you may use

1. Add a transparent layer above the country field and give it higher z-index.
2. Use JQuery and return false; when onClick and onSelect events are invoked.

Comment: first one looks good , i will give it a try and let you know, thanks

Comment: @user3848698 You're welcome, just let me know if you need any help.

Answer (score -3):

Add `disabled` attribute in input as you can see below.

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" class="select2-input" role="combobox" aria-expanded="true" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-owns="select2-results-1" id="s2id_autogen1_search" placeholder="" aria-activedescendant="select2-result-label-7" disabled>
```

Comment: This would not work for an already initialised and already active select2 dropdown.