# Remove country field woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

Is any possibility to remove the country field from the checkoput page and add a city dropdown selector field.

I'm using WC City Select plugin but it's not working.

What should I do?

Comment: solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29588992/woocommerce-remove-country-field-in-cart-shipping

Comment: 2nd solution : https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/configuring-woocommerce-settings/

Answer (score 0):

Remove some content in file plugin `woocommerce\includes\wc-template-functions.php`

Around line no : 1836 to 1843

```
$field = '<select name="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '" id="' . esc_attr( $args['id'] ) . '" ' . $args['autocomplete'] . ' class="country_to_state country_select ' . esc_attr( implode( ' ', $args['input_class'] ) ) .'" ' . implode( ' ', $custom_attributes ) . '>'
                        . '<option value="">'.__( 'Select a country&hellip;', 'woocommerce' ) .'</option>';
foreach ( $countries as $ckey => $cvalue ) {
                    $field .= '<option value="' . esc_attr( $ckey ) . '" '. selected( $value, $ckey, false ) . '>'. __( $cvalue, 'woocommerce' ) .'</option>';
                }
```

Remove that code for `country`.

remove this code in picture [image]

Thanks is Advance.